# Why while cycle causes problem with pointers?

Tags: c++, while-loop, function-pointers

I'm new in c++, I started studying pointers recently, I was trying to make a simple test program:

```
struct test {
    int a;
    double b;
    test *next;

    test() : a(0), b(0), next(nullptr) {}

    test(int v1, double v2) : a(v1), b(v2), next(nullptr) {}

    test(int v1, double v2, test *n) : a(v1), b(v2), next(n) {}
}
```

Than in the main I tried this:

```
int count = 0;
test *p;
test *p2 = new test();

do {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout++;
    if (count>5) {
        p = p2;
    }
}while(p==0);

while (p==0) {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    count++;
    if (count>5) {
        p = p2;
    }
}
```

The do-while cycle works, it prints the message as I want.

In the while cycle it doesn't, it didn't even bother to enter. I try to change the condition (from equal to not equal) "for some reason" and the terminal started to print the message in loop.

I even try to change, in the condition, '0' with 'nullptr', but the result is the same for both cycles. I try to print the location of the second pointer, p2, and it's in memory. Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Surely that's a typo on `cout++;` and instead you meant `count++`

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a typo I make copying the code from the virtual machine.

Comment: Please don't post code here that you can't compile, because then people start guessing about things. Instead, [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]. As new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It works as expected. From the do-while loop condition `p` is non zero(or nullptr) and that makes control not get into the while loop. It is hard to tell you an answer since I don't know what you want.

Comment: Basically `0` and `nullptr` are the same values. And it is always a good practice to use `nullptr` since it is not confusing whether it is a pointer or an integer.

Comment: What I want is that the program enters the while cycle, which it doesn't.

Comment: you could please add complete compilable code? rather in bits and pieces [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What are you trying to achieve with the `loop`?

Comment: Well debug it and look at the value of p. It should be address

Comment: `test *p;` should be `test *p = nullptr;` Your loop is reading an uninitialised variable, which is  [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so the entire program is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

```
do{...}while(p == 0)
```

it means that the cycle should execute until `p` is **different** from `0`, if `p` is equal to `0` the loop will continue, if it's **different** it will exit the loop.

So if it is ended, `p` will be different from 0.

The next loop will only execute if p is **equal** to `0`, see what I mean?

Here is a [working sample](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy-i6yjZL)

Comment: Yes, but still it doesn't work even if I reset the value of p to 0 or nullptr.

Comment: It works for me, if i place `p = 0` after the `do while`, I'll show you an example...

Comment: That's weird, how many times it printed the message in the while-cycle?

Comment: @Gello, the `do while` only executes once since p is different from 0, but that is for you to know, I'm just showing you that if u reset p to 0 it will enter the second cycle

Comment: Because in my terminal the do-while cycle still works, but the while cycle enters only one time with that code..

Comment: p is uninitialized, so it can assume different values in different compilers, it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks weird but this is the issue: You change the value of `p` in the first do while. This loop exists because p is no longer 0. Then how could it enter the second loop which has the same condition? You must reset the value of p.

Comment: I tried, even if I change the value of p in 0 after the do-while cycle, it doesn't enter in the while cycle.

Comment: How are you changing the value of p to zero? Show us some code. This should work. However you could easily rewrite the code without using p in the condition. You already have a count variable

Comment: I tried with nullptr, it's the same. The do-while cycle woks as expected, the while cycle doesn't.

Comment: There could be many variables: perhaps you are not compilling the new code but running the old one(can happen in visual studio) or lots of other things. You are lost and we cannot help you... kidding..just debug

Comment: sergiu reznicencu after the do-while-cycle and before while-cycle:
p = nullptr;

Comment: @Gello With that, I checked the while loop is executed once. Isn't it something that you expected?

Comment: Hmm...use in the second loop p==nullptr..perhaps

Comment: @Hanjoung Lee in my code the program doesn't even enter once in the loop. Even with that, it should enter more than one..

Comment: It is weird, and it is expected to run just once. For me I get one more "Hello" line with putting `p = 0`.

Comment: Well of course an extra hello should be printed. Count is not resseted so it should immediatly set p to p2. We all assumed the execution never entered the second loop.